# :before "shape" contained in div css - no overflow

Tags: css

I'm trying to get this circle clipped by the div: so it's neatly contained inside and there's no overflow. I'm having a hard time finding an elegant solution.

[Example of end goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKlqU.png)

```css
.wrapper{
  background: #efefef;
  height: 250px;
}

.wrapper::before{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 border-radius: 500px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F38A00, #EC6E00 100%);
 position: absolute;
 right: 20%;
    content: '';
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify, `overflow: hidden`  and `position: relative;` on wrapper.

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  background: #efefef;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.wrapper::before{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 border-radius: 500px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F38A00, #EC6E00 100%);
 position: absolute;
 right: 20%;
    content: '';
      
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Why would you use a container, `position: relative;` and `overflow: hidden;` on the `.wrapper` class should be enough.